# Is there a way to hide a method in Xcode autocomplete if a variable is not set?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autocomplete

I am creating a class which can contain a `NSString` or a `NSMutableString`. If the class is instantiated with `NSString` based constructor, I set `isMutable` to `NO` and I want to hide the `NSMutableString` related methods. Is there any way to mark methods using compiler directives or something like `#unavailable if (!isMutable)` so that Xcode does not show that? I cannot create sub-class this in case. How to do this?

```
- (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)string {
    // ...
}

- (instancetype)initWithMutableString:(NSMutableString *)string {
    // ..
    _isMutable = YES;
}

#unavailable (!isMutable)  // Check _isMutable ?
(void)appendString:(NSString *)string {
    //...
}
```

Comment: No, there is no such directive.
You will need do this in same way like it's done in foundation: NSString - NSMutableString, NSDictionary - NSMutableDictionary ...

Answer (score 0):

Follow this reference :

[Cocoa: Testing to find if an NSString is immutable or mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092637/cocoa-testing-to-find-if-an-nsstring-is-immutable-or-mutable)

All the answers are very descriptive and you'll get more idea why this should be done or you should find out another workaround for this.

Comment: There are specific methods to create mutable vs. immutable strings. I am looking for a way if I called an immutable string, I want to hide the methods.